# Paypal IPN returns Invalid in python pyramid framework

Tags: python, paypal, pyramid, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have been trying to implement paypal IPN listener but it keeps giving me invalid. I am using 
python pyramid framework and requests library. Please help.

```
PP_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
parameters = {}
parameters = request.POST.copy()
parameters['cmd']='_notify-validate'
params = urlencode(parameters)

status = requests.post(PP_URL, params=params)

status = status.text

print status
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Also I am using https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

to test the ipn listener.

Comment: Can you include the output of `parameters` before sending it off to us?

Answer (score 0):

What is likely occurring is this:

This line will copy the POST request exactly as is, which is already encoded:

```
parameters = request.POST.copy()
```

Then you call this line, which encodes the encoded line:

```
params = urlencode(parameters)
```

This causes double encoding, which would be problematic.

You should be able to remove the params = urlencode(parameters) line and be fine. If this doesnt work, then urldecode the POST request, append the notify-validate, then urlencode again.